# TypeError in Solidity, when trying to deploy the blockchain in local machine

Tags: ethereum, solidity, ethers.js

I've been trying to deploy a smart contract locally, but when i run the JavaScript i'm facing this error, can someone help me out

Error:

```
Deploying, please wait...
TypeError: no matching function (argument="key", value="deployTransaction", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.2.3)
    at makeError (/home/sanju/Solidity Tutorial/hh-fcc/ethers-simple-storage/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/utils/errors.js:114:21)
    at assert (/home/sanju/Solidity Tutorial/hh-fcc/ethers-simple-storage/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/utils/errors.js:138:15)
    at assertArgument (/home/sanju/Solidity Tutorial/hh-fcc/ethers-simple-storage/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/utils/errors.js:150:5)
    at Interface.getFunctionName (/home/sanju/Solidity Tutorial/hh-fcc/ethers-simple-storage/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/abi/interface.js:337:39)
    at buildWrappedMethod (/home/sanju/Solidity Tutorial/hh-fcc/ethers-simple-storage/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/contract/contract.js:308:34)
    at BaseContract.getFunction (/home/sanju/Solidity Tutorial/hh-fcc/ethers-simple-storage/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/contract/contract.js:686:22)
    at Object.get (/home/sanju/Solidity Tutorial/hh-fcc/ethers-simple-storage/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/contract/contract.js:627:39)
    at main (/home/sanju/Solidity Tutorial/hh-fcc/ethers-simple-storage/deploy.js:32:45)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  code: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT',
  argument: 'key',
  value: 'deployTransaction'
}
```

JavaScript Code: Node v18.17.1

Code:

```js
const ethers = require("ethers");
const fs = require("fs");

// we can only use await keyword inside async functions

async function main() {
  const rpcURL = "http://127.0.0.1:7545";
  const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider(rpcURL);

  const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(
    "0xdae2a8f600d25556f9863f2a5f5134241fc860f5469e71e6205f5b1dc517c576",
    provider
  );

  const abi = fs.readFileSync("./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.abi", "utf-8");

  const binary = fs.readFileSync(
    "./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.bin",
    "utf-8"
  );

  const contractFactory = new ethers.ContractFactory(abi, binary, wallet);
  console.log("Deploying, please wait...");
  const contract = await contractFactory.deploy(); // STOP here, wait for the contract to deploy
  const transactionReceipt = await contract.deployTransaction.wait(1);
  console.log(
    `Here is the deployment transaction: ${contract.deployTransaction}`
  );
  console.log(`Here is the transaction receipt: ${transactionReceipt}`);
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Solidity - 0.8.7-fixed

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity 0.8.7;

contract SimpleStorage {
    uint256 favoriteNumber;

    struct People {
        uint256 favoriteNumber;
        string name;
    }
    // uint256[] public anArray;
    People[] public people;

    mapping(string => uint256) public nameToFavoriteNumber;

    function store(uint256 _favoriteNumber) public {
        favoriteNumber = _favoriteNumber;
    }

    function retrieve() public view returns (uint256) {
        return favoriteNumber;
    }

    function addPerson(string memory _name, uint256 _favoriteNumber) public {
        people.push(People(_favoriteNumber, _name));
        nameToFavoriteNumber[_name] = _favoriteNumber;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to deploy the smart contract locally, my configurations include

1. ethers.js - 6.2.3
2. solc - 0.8.7
3. ganache
4. node - v18.17.1

Answer (score 0):

You can try swapping the line

```
const transactionReceipt = await contract.deployTransaction.wait(1);
```

with

```
const transactionReceipt = await contract.wait();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `contract.deployed()`;

`await contract.deployed()`

https://docs.ethers.org/v4/api-contract.html#deploying-a-contract